# Stripe Subscription Coupon Not Applied on First Billing Cycle

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am automatically applying a 50% discount to first-time subscribers of my service using coupon code 'FIRSTTIME.' However, I'm noticing the 50% discount is consistently being applied to the *second* billing cycle and not the first. The billing cycles are weekly, and I want the first billing cycle to receive the 50% discount.

In Stripe, my coupon is configured as follows:

- ID: FIRSTTIME
- Percent Off: 50% Off
- Duration: Once
- Redeem By: 2016/12/31
- Valid: True

Additionally, you can see my **views.py** below:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubscriptionPaymentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            token = stripe.Token.create(
                card = {
                  "number": form.cleaned_data['number'],
                  "exp_month": form.cleaned_data['expiration'].month,
                  "exp_year": form.cleaned_data['expiration'].year,
                  "cvc": form.cleaned_data['cvc'],
                  "name": form.cleaned_data['name']
                },
            )
            c = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer.stripe_id)
            c.sources.create(source=token.id)
            try:
                sub = c.subscriptions.retrieve(subscription.stripe_id)
                sub.plan = subscription.weekly_plan
                sub.save()
            except:
                sub = c.subscriptions.create(plan=subscription.weekly_plan)
                sub.coupon = "FIRSTTIME"
                sub.save()
                subscription.stripe_id = sub.id
                subscription.save()
                subscription.send_subscription_email(email)
            subscription.name = form.cleaned_data['name']           
            subscription.checked_out = True
            subscription.status = "Paid"
            subscription.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

I'm using Django on Ubuntu with an Apache2 server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple, logical mistake I made, which I have corrected. I was creating a customer object, then creating a subscription object, and lastly applying the discount code to the already-created subscription object. Creating a subscription object immediately bills the customer, and because I applied the coupon after creating the initial subscription, it wasn't being applied on the first billing cycle.

In order to bill the customer on the first cycle, it is better to associate the coupon with the customer object when you first create the customer.

Comment: Be careful.  This is what Stripe docs have to say about apply discounts on customers
`we recommend adding coupons to subscriptions, not customers, unless you’re certain you’ll always want to discount all recurring charges for a customer, even on subscriptions added later.`
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/discounts#discounting-customers